# Trying to match a nearly repeating pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a very specific pattern for my uni project. Unfortunately I'm stuck. The pattern goes as follows:

> - A word or number of length 1 or 2 followed by `,`.
> - This is repeated for four times and then followed by `;` instead of `,`.
> - This whole thing repeats itself for exactly four times but without `;` at the end.

Examples would be:

```
SR,SR,SR,AR;0,11,22,33;SG,1,23,DG;SY,BY,CY,DY
36,AR,CR,DR;SB,10,16,22;SG,13,BG,DG;SY,0,20,BY
```

Whereas these should not match (look for the commas and semicolons):

```
SR,SR;SR,AR;0,11,22,33;SG,1,23,DG;SY,BY,CY,DY
36,AR,CR,DR,SB,10,16,22;SG,13,BG,DG;SY,0,20,BY
```

The closest I got is

```
((([ABCDS][RBGY])|\d{1,2})[,;]){16}
```

But this does match the negative examples above.

This is my current workaround:

```
public boolean matching(String arguments) {
    String[] strings = arguments.split(";");
    if (strings.length != 4) return false;
    for (String s : strings) {
        String[] strings1 = s.split(",");
        if (strings1.length != 4) return false;
        for (String s1 : strings1) {
            if (!s1.matches(POSITION_PATTERN)) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, this is not an ideal solution and very inefficient.

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried? No one here wants to right out a large parser (or in your case a regex statement) for you from scratch.  Paste the code you tried into the question and someone will help you fix it.

Comment: The description actually doesn't match the examples you've given. The letter groups occur **four** times, not three, and the last occurence is not followed by a comma. Likewise, the entire pattern doesn't end with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the following pattern:

```
(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})(?:,(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})){3}(?:;(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})(?:,(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})){3}){3}
```

Explanation:

```
(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})          match two letter or 1-2 digits
(?:,(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})){3}  followed by a comma and another two letters or
                                   1-2 digits, that quantity 3 times
(?:;                               then match semicolon
    (?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})(?:,(?:[ABCDS][RBGY]|\d{1,2})){3}){3}
                                   followed by the previous pattern 3 more times
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the pattern doesn't match your sample data. I suspect you mean the letter groups to be repeated four times, right?

A simple one could look like this: `((\w{1,2}(,|(?:\w))){4}(;|$)){4}`

It just does, step by step, what you asked for.
See [DEMO](https://regexr.com/474kd)

Comment: Close one. But it matches 36ARCRDR;SB101622;SG13BGDG;SY0200BY which it shouldn't.